# SQL: Display students with same teacher on two courses

Tags: sql

Been trying to solve this query for couple hours now.

I have the following tables:

```
    Student 
    (StudenNumber* INT, ID TEXT, Fname TEXT, Lname TEXT, Institute TEXT, EnrollYear INT)

    Teacher
    (ID* TEXT, Fname TEXT, Lname TEXT, Insitutue TEXT)

    Course
    (ID* TEXT, Name TEXT, Type TEXT, Weeks INT, Period INT, Year INT, Subject TEXT, Teacher TEXT)

    Institute
    (Name* TEXT, Faculty TEXT)

    Subject
    (Name* TEXT, Examination TEXT, Insitute TEXT)

    Grade
    (Course* TEXT,Student* INT, Grade INT)

    Examination
    (ID* TEXT, ExaminationName* TEXT)
```

And I am trying to get display all the students that have had the same teacher in two courses (removing duplicates).

My query is not returning exactly what I am looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.Fname, E.Lname
FROM STUDENT E
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(A.TEACHER)
              FROM COURSE A, COURSE B
              WHERE A.Teacher = B.Teacher
              GROUP BY Teacher
              having COUNT(*) = 2);
```

Comment: Your sub-query needs to reference E. (Poor choice of table alias...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `COURSE` as a mapping table, it connects each student to a course (and thus teacher).  From there, you can group by student/teacher pairs and just count the number of rows.

```
SELECT
  s.fname || ' ' || s.lname as student_name
  ,t.fname || ' ' || f.lname as teacher_name
  ,count(1) as courses_together
FROM
  COURSE c
LEFT JOIN
  TEACHER t     --grab teachers' names
  ON
      c.teacher = t.id
LEFT JOIN
  GRADE g       --this is our map table linking courses to students
  ON
      c.id = g.course
LEFT JOIN
  STUDENT s
  ON
      g.student = s.id
GROUP BY
  student_name, last_name
HAVING
   count(1) > 1
```

Comment: I am getting NULL values in return. The correct answer should return 2 students.

Comment: One of the joins is failing and/or some of the fields do not have text in them.  Are you getting ONLY null values, or are you getting NULLs plus the two students?